# TYPO3 rename Appearance -> Layouts of gridelements Extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-gridelements

I'm trying to rename the layout labels of the Appearance tab in a gridelements module.

I can easily change labels of standard content elements via:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
layout.types {
    textpic {
        altLabels {
            0 = Standard
            1 = Bild rechts
            2 = Bild links (klein)
            3 = Farbig
        }
        removeItems = 4, 5, 100
    }
    image {
        altLabels {
            0 = Standard
            1 = kleines Bild
        }
        removeItems = 2, 3, 4, 5, 100
    }
}}
```

However I'm not able to figure this out. From the documentation I got: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

I found something, in german, that seems to work for another extension (news) https://jweiland.net/typo3/codebeispiele/tsconfig/labels-in-flexforms-anpassen.html

There're no different labels for those layouts depending on the content of table tt_content column tx_gridelements_backend_layout, like in my example above for table tt_content and column CType.

I'd appreciate help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot or something similar to show, what exactly you want to rename? I guess it is not the "layout" drop down as in your example, but it's not clear which field you actually want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this the following way:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {     
    layout.types {
        gridelements_pi1 {
            altLabels.1 = Change item           # change item
            addItems.400 = New Item             # add item
            removeItems = 3                     # remove item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that's not the solution. With you code you will change the labels of all of the gridelements, not of a specific type only.